# If you connect to your computer via its own IP does the traffic leave your NIC then comes back?

Tags: networking, tcp, network-protocols

I believe that if you use 127.0.0.1 the traffic never leaves the NIC, but I was wondering whether the same was true when you use the actual IP address of the computer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it does not.  Your operating system will recognize that it is a local address and internally loop-back even though the address is bound to a physical network port.

As a simple test, pull the network cable.  You'll still be able to communicate locally.  (Note that a DHCP served address may get revoked if the OS detects the cable has been removed; you may have to configure a static IP address before trying this test.)

Also, hubs (and presumably many/most switches) will not pass outgoing packets back down the wire so "going out on the wire" wouldn't work with most networking equipment, either.

Comment: Wondering what if 2 IPs 2 NICs (same subnet) in the same box?  would loop-back still happen?

Comment: It should, yes.  The OS generally matches against all known "local" IP addresses.  You can verify with a hub, a switch in "snoop" mode, or just watching the transmit lights on an otherwise quiet network interface.